# European orbital rocket companies?

Tags: rockets, launch-vehicle

Besides the obvious

- [Arianespace](https://www.arianespace.com/) (France) with Ariane 5/6
- [Avio](https://www.avio.com/) (Italy) with Vega/Vega C

I found a few other new companies that haven't launched yet (to my knowledge), such as

- [RFA](https://www.rfa.space/) (Germany)
- [Isar Aerospace](https://www.isaraerospace.com/) (Germany)
- [Pangea Aerospace](https://pangeaaerospace.com) (Spain)
- [Skyrora](https://www.skyrora.com) (UK)
- [Orbex](https://orbex.space) (UK)

Are there any other?

Comment: Russia is in Europe, you're missing one of the biggest players.

Comment: Does [Dawn](https://www.dawnaerospace.com) classify as "rocket company"?

Comment: @Ludo that's suborbital? For the same reason I didn't include 
Copenhagen Suborbitals or MORABA.

Comment: @BojanKogoj [Their roadmap for MkIII](https://www.dawnaerospace.com/dawn-mkii-aurora) includes orbital insertion, but that's not within their current capabilities. Also, it's a plane, not a rocket in the classical sense.

Comment: @Ludo True. Add an answer or edit question if you want.

Comment: Is Eurockot with its (ICBM derived) Rockot still active?

Comment: This should help: https://europeanspaceflight.com/european-rocket-index/

Comment: Cool list, although some of them are only doing suborbital or are inactive?

Comment: None of them have launched to orbit yet except Avio and Ariane Group. My starting assumption is that the payload kg column means "to orbit". The guy who runs the site (Andrew Parsonson) has lots of fact sheets on individual launchers which are available on his twitter feed.

Answer (score 1):

[Dawn Aerospace](https://www.dawnaerospace.com) (The Netherlands) aims to provide orbital services with their MkIII space plane, the [planned successor to their MkII](https://www.dawnaerospace.com/dawn-mkii-aurora).

Maybe not a "rocket company" in the traditional sense and admittedly the MkIII exists only in the future.

Comment: Well actually, Dawn is testing their spacecraft in New Zealand, and operates out of NZ, not just the Netherlands
They are flying out of a remote valley plateau.
You can find official video of it.
Their Mk.II suborbital spaceplane has completed multiple flights, and multiple of those on rocket power, in high climb rates.
Their final design, Mk.III, will do a suborbital hop, then detach a second stage (expendable, for now), to insert the payload.
It's genuinly one of the coolest rocket companies out there, and I can't wait to see what they do.